# if condition always returns true (Java)

Tags: java, date, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement a date system that inevitably displays tomorrows day, month and year.

The problem I am having is that the one of the if statements always returns true, and the ones after this one always return false.

Here is part of my code:

```
public class dateVerification {

    int tomorrowDay = 0;
    int tomorrowMonth = 0;
    int tomorrowYear = 0;
    int day = 0;
    int month = 0;
    int year = 0;

    public void date() {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the day");
        day = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the month");
        month = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the year");
        year = myScanner.nextInt();

        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10) {
                    if (day < 31) {
                        tomorrowDay = day + 1;
                    } else {
                        tomorrowDay = 1;
                        tomorrowMonth = month + 1;
                    }
                }
                break;
```

The line that is returning true is:

```
 if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10)
```

And everything else is returning false, i.e. my case 2 statement

```
if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
```

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: You `case 1` on `month`, so that should not come as a surprise that `month == 1` is always true, right?

Comment: What input you are passing in `month` variable??

Comment: Where is this statement in code? `if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the `month` field.

In case 1 the month is always 1.

```
 switch (month) {
            case 1:  //mount = 1 !!
                if (month == 1 ||...
     //
 }
```

Comment: Cheers, I understand your reasoning, But I how would I go about testing the other months without adding more if statements?

Comment: `switch (month) {
            case 1:  //... break;
            case 2:  //... break;
            .....
            case 12:  //...break;
}`

Comment: thank you! I realised my mistake. I had to do some reading up on switch statements. I have now got it working. :D

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get tomorrow in java is

```
public Date nextDate(Date currentDate) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTime(currentDate); 
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is in this part:

```
 } else {
                        tomorrowDay = 1;
                        tomorrowMonth = month + 1;
```

Since you want to increase the month when the day is 31, you should change it to

```
 } else {
                        tomorrowDay = 1;
                        month = month + 1;
```

for the month to increase and exit the loop, orelse you never leave it because month (which is what you are checking never changes value)